# Not able to launch 2nd Instance instance in AWS Free tier

Tags: amazon-web-services

While launching 2nd instance getting below error

you have requested more vcpu capacity than your current vcpu limit of 1 allows for the instance bucket that the specified instance type belongs to. please visit http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request to request an adjustment to this limit.

Comment: I think the message is pretty clear? What's exactly is unclear about it?

Comment: Created two vpc's in same region and trying to create instance for each vpc but while creating 2nd instance for 2nd vpc that timi I'm getting above mentioned error

Comment: Any help to clear this issue

Comment: Which instance type did you attempt to launch, and what instance types are _currently running?_

Comment: .t2micro instance is using for launh and currently running type also .t2micro

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is a billing discount. It does not impact your ability to use any services. If the resources you use are within the limits imposed by the AWS Free Tier, you simply won't be charged for those resources. Thus, **the AWS Free tier is not the cause of this error**.

From [On-Demand Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-on-demand-instances.html#ec2-on-demand-instances-limits):

> There is a limit on the number of running On-Demand Instances per AWS account per Region. On-Demand Instance limits are managed in terms of the number of virtual central processing units (vCPUs) that your running On-Demand Instances are using, regardless of the instance type.

You did not tell us what Instance Type you are running, or attempted to run, but it sounds like **you have exceeded this vCPU limit**. This is more likely to happen with large or expensive instance types, or instance types that use GPU resources. You can **view the limits** in the Amazon EC2 management console by clicking **Limits** and then searching for `vCPU`.

If this is impacting your use of AWS, you can **request an increase to these default limits**.

See: [Calculate a vCPU limit increase request for an Amazon EC2 On-Demand Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-on-demand-instance-vcpu-increase/)